# How to unlock table after calling a Spring stored procedure

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure that moves a bunch of rows from one table to another. I'm using spring's `StoredProcedure` class to call the procedure. Here's the code:

```
public class MigracionPagoMasivoNormalATemporalStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure    {
...
    public Long ejecutar(final Long idPagoMasivo) {
        final Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> outs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        inputs.put(ID_UPLOAD_HEADER, idPagoMasivo);
        inputs.put(ID_UPLOAD_HEADER_TEMPORAL, 0);

        try {
            outs = super.execute(inputs);
            return Long.valueOf((Integer) outs.get(ID_UPLOAD_HEADER_TEMPORAL));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // TODO dcalderon: Controlar excepciones
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new Long(0);
     }
}
```

This procedure is called successfully and does exactly what it was intended to. Problem is I have to query the migrated rows afterwards. This time I use hibernate. Both method work well separated, but I assume the stored procedure is locking the table somehow and preventing the query to be executed.

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_PM_MIGRARLOTENORMALATEMPORAL(@ID_UPLOAD_HEADER int, @ID_UPLOAD_HEADER_TEMPORAL int OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  /* Se migra el pago masivo de la tabla normal a la tabla temporal*/
 INSERT INTO UPLOAD_HEADER_TEMPORAL (id_upload_header, ...)
 SELECT [id], ...
 FROM UPLOAD_HEADER WHERE [id] = @ID_UPLOAD_HEADER

 SET @ID_UPLOAD_HEADER_TEMPORAL = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

 /* Se migra el detalle del pago masivo de la tabla normal a la temporal */
 INSERT INTO UPLOAD_RECORD_TEMPORAL (id_header, ...)
 SELECT @ID_UPLOAD_HEADER_TEMPORAL, ... FROM UPLOAD_RECORD
 WHERE id_header = @ID_UPLOAD_HEADER

 /* Se hace update al estado del detalle en la tabla temporal */
 UPDATE UPLOAD_RECORD_TEMPORAL SET status = 0 WHERE id_header = @ID_UPLOAD_HEADER_TEMPORAL

 COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

My question is, how can I execute the query, recover the lock of the table? (I already debbuged the code and I know it gets locked in the query). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While insertion the table will get locked

You should wait that time frame 
if your not bothering about new data , you can go for any dirty read methods like NOLOCK

or read uncommitted isolation level - this method is not suggested in any aspects

Suggestion - try to use Transaction as much as Atomic to avoid locking